# RxJs - Get last emitted value from observable within same observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have an observable, where I wish to use the previous value emitted by the observable to emit the next value (this will be used for the purpose of preventing doing the same expensive operation multiple times)

```js
interface PersonInfo {
  name: string;
  data: string;
}

const names$ = new Subject<string[]>();
const personInfo$ = new BehaviorSubject<PersonInfo[]>([]);

const namesData$ = names$.pipe(
  // Rather than getting the latest value from personInfo$ i would like to use the last value emitted by this observable
  withLatestFrom(personInfo$),
  map(([names, personsInfo]) => {
    // Remove persons who do not have a name in the names$
    const persons = personsInfo.filter((personInfo) =>
      names.includes(personInfo.name)
    );

    names.forEach((name) => {
      if (!persons.some((person) => person.name === name)) {
        persons.push({ name, data: getPersonData(name) });
      }
    });

    personInfo$.next(persons);
    return persons;
  })
);

const getPersonData = (name: string) => {
  // This is an expensive operation and we do not wish to call it multiple times
  console.log(`getPersonsData called by ${name}`);
  return name;
};
```

This is what I have come up with so far, and although it works as intended, I feel like this is bad practice, and I really do not want to rely on the personInfo$ BehaviourSubject. I tried to use withLatestFrom(namesData$), but this does not work for two reasons:

- namesData$ is being accessed before it has been initialized
- the observable will never emit anyway due to the withLatestFrom which needs to emit at least once.

Is there some pipe / other clever way to do this without having to use an extra (unnecessary) Observable as I did?

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-rqycry?file=index.ts)

Comment: seems to me like you might be happy with _pairwise_ https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/pairwise

Comment: @robertotomás I don't really see how, but perhaps I am overlooking something.

Comment: why not just `const personsInfo: PersonInfo[] = [];`?

Comment: even better use object not array, it will make getting the person info `O(1)` because now it's `O(n)`

Comment: @Robert this is possible, but still smells a little. There is no guarantee that the array will always reflect the previous value of the observable. (If anybody in the future were to think they should modify this array there would be trouble).

Comment: can you please look at the answer I just posted

Comment: @Robert Using object probably would be better indeed.

Comment: what do you mean by `If anybody in the future were to think they should modify this array there would be trouble`

Comment: @Robert I am working with a large dev team, although this works for now, someone might decide to modify this value in the future. Thus, I prefer code that uses RxJs with "stateless" programming as it is more maintainable.

Comment: someone can modify `namesData$` still, `BehaviourSubject` is not stateless, you need to add comments explaining the situation, I'm working with a large dev team too but we never delete or modify code arbitrary

Comment: @Robert Exactly, that is why I asked for help, as my solution has the same issue. Although unlikely that someone will modify the object in the future, I've seen many similar situations where code has broken and it is very hard to figure out why. If you do not agree, that is fine, but I am looking for a solution that does not have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

from my understanding `personData` is just a cache of the data that come from `getPersonsData`, so it will be better to be object and not an Observable, a BehaviourSubject or an array

here is my full solution

```
interface PersonInfo {
  name: string;
  data: string;
}

const names$ = new Subject<string[]>();
const personData: {[key: string]: string} = {};

const namesData$ = names$.pipe(
  map(names) => {
    return names.map(name => {
        if (personData[name]) {
            return {name, data: personData[name]};
        } else {
            const data = getPersonData(name);
            personData[name] = data;
            return {name, data};
        }
    });
  })
);

const getPersonData = (name: string) => {
  // This is an expensive operation and we do not wish to call it multiple times
  console.log(`getPersonsData called by ${name}`);
  return name;
};
```

Comment: This works and is better than what I did initially, but as mentioned in comments it is somewhat unsafe as there is no guarantee that personData will contain the last emitted value (another developer may choose to modify this value in the future)

Comment: I have one more thing that might help, https://github.com/robertIsaac/data-structures/blob/master/src/most-recently-used-cache.ts this is a custom data structure for caching